# Who runs scripts inside /etc/cron.hourly if anacron is enabled?

Tags: scripts, cron, anacron

I've read that if `anacron` is enabled `cron` doesn't run the scripts inside cron.weekly/hourly/daily/hourly, as not to run them twice. So `anacron` takes responsability on that folders.

However `anacron` doesn't work with hourly scripts. So, who runs /etc/cron.hourly?

Sorry if it is a begginer question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at `/etc/crontab`, you'll see:

```
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

Then check the status of `cron`:

```
$ service cron status
cron start/running, process 1041
```

`anacron` itself doesn't run as a service/daemon, but as a cron job: `/etc/cron.d/anacron`.
So `cron` is running and checking if `anacron` is present for the daily, weekly and monthly tasks, but not for the hourly tasks. `cron` runs the hourly tasks.

Comment: off topic: is there a reason to choose [any-hour]:17 minutes, any day at 6:25, etc, instead of doing them at :00 o' clock?

Comment: @redraw Not off topic :) See http://askubuntu.com/questions/149490/what-is-the-story-behind-the-default-times-set-in-etc-crontab