# Setting daily backups on laptop with cron/anacron on 16.10

Tags: backup, cron, 16.10, anacron

I have similar questions to [confusion about cron and anacron (setting up backup schedule for rsnapshot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768266/confusion-about-cron-and-anacron-setting-up-backup-schedule-for-rsnapshot), but there weren't answered either.

### Problem

My problem is to have a backup routine on daily basis on a laptop. So, my first idea was to set it in a `crontab` like

```
$ crontab -e
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:   
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# I guess as user I have no access to /var/log from this crontab, do I?
@daily ~/my-backups.sh >> ~/.log/my-backup.log
```

and then the script `my-backups.sh` should run everyday at midnight (`0 0 * * *`), right?

Ok, and after reading the documentation I found out about anacron. But then the problem arises as the script is not run. From the documentation I understand that if the computer was off when the daily routine was supposed to be executed by `cron` then `anacron` should fire it up on start up. But that is not happening either.

Do I need to do another setup? (From the documentation I assumed it was not needed and that it should work out of the box, but is not happening.)

### Question

How can I set up cron/anacron to execute a daily script, and in case the computer was off at the time of execution, it should run the script on startup or after some time after startup.

### Version using `cron.daily`

I modified my backup script changing to `cron.daily` as suggested. My test script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

date +%Y-%m-%d >> /var/log/backup.log
```

Then add it to `/etc/cron.daily` as a symbolic link

```
sudo ln -s ~/bin/my-backup /etc/cron.daily/backup
```

I checked, and the script and the symlink both have execute permissions.

Then, today, I started my machine around 9, and the first entries on `/var/log/syslog` are around that time, but there is no sign of `cron.daily` there.

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep cron
Feb 16 09:05:15 box cron[981]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Feb 16 09:05:15 box cron[981]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Feb 16 09:17:01 box CRON[4574]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 16 10:17:01 box CRON[6453]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 16 11:17:01 box CRON[6878]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 16 12:17:01 box CRON[7310]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 16 13:14:01 box CRON[7582]: (root) CMD (   test -x /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest && /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest --crond)
Feb 16 13:17:01 box CRON[7595]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 16 14:17:02 box CRON[8134]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Also, the last time of the anacron executed was yesterday

```
$ sudo cat /var/spool/anacron/cron.daily 
20170215
```

And I check, and my script is listed in the `cron.daily`

```
$ run-parts --test --report /etc/cron.daily
/etc/cron.daily/0anacron
/etc/cron.daily/apport
/etc/cron.daily/apt-compat
/etc/cron.daily/backup
/etc/cron.daily/bsdmainutils
/etc/cron.daily/cracklib-runtime
/etc/cron.daily/dpkg
/etc/cron.daily/google-chrome
/etc/cron.daily/google-talkplugin
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate
/etc/cron.daily/man-db
/etc/cron.daily/mlocate
/etc/cron.daily/passwd
/etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest
/etc/cron.daily/update-notifier-common
/etc/cron.daily/upstart
```

Comment: I setup cron to create a `.tar` backup file of my laptop every morning and email it to myself in the cloud: https://askubuntu.com/questions/917562/backup-linux-configuration-scripts-and-documents-to-gmail/922493#922493

Answer (score 1):

Place you script to `/etc/cron.daily` and you will get exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Will it run as `root` there? Or as my user?

Comment: It will run as root.

Comment: I move the script to the `/etc/cron.daily`, and run it manually and worked. However, today after startup (after the daily hour of `cron`) the anacron job was not executed. I checked, and the script has no extension, but there is not info about anacron.

Comment: Can you post the script to your question? You can't use path like `~/` there. You need to add full path like `/home/xxxxx/....`.

Comment: The script right now is a test one, just to see if it is executed. See my changes.

Comment: Did you ever end up resolving this?