# How to backup Ubuntu and programs settings?

Tags: backup, settings

I want to backup user settings and programs configuration.

I came from this question [How to backup settings and list of installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/how-to-backup-settings-and-list-of-installed-packages) . There, settings and personal data are backup, not only configurations.

**I don't want to backup:**

- personal data;
- `.bashrc` , `.profile`, ... (*if I don't install a program that was previously installed, there may be an error*);

**I want to backup:**

- All installed programs configurations
- Ubuntu configurations (keyboard, date, tweaks, ...)

*I don't bother to backup a program configuration that I won't install, because normally it has low memory size.*

I guess that if I backup all etc folder and hidden files on home directory (except `.bashrc` and `.profile`) what I want will be done, can someone confirm it to me?

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/917562/backup-linux-configuration-scripts-and-documents-to-gmail/922493#922493

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, the safest method is to backup all hidden files from your home folder from your reference computer and paste it in your new user,

EXCEPT

- `.bashrc`
- `.profile`
- `.cache`

Please clean up your trash to save space, because trash is stored in `.local`

Answer (score 0):

You might look into `Aptik`. It lets you backup and re-add all PPAs, installed packages (PPA/system/manually installed Deb), application settings, icons, themes, users/groups, data of Home directory and schedule tasks with a single click. Further more you can back and restore packages individually.

Please see these two web sites for more information and how to install...

http://www.teejeetech.in/p/aptik.html

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/01/aptik-backup-ppa-installed-apps-users-data/