# Take backup and send to cloud

Tags: backup, cloud

I am looking for a software which can take backup of my Ubuntu Desktop and send it to google cloud. Software should have below features:

1. Encryption
2. Compression
3. Auto sync with cloud

Comment: I have a daily backup that runs every morning. It backs up what's important to me and emails it to gmail which I can access from any device and location: https://askubuntu.com/questions/917562/backup-linux-configuration-scripts-and-documents-to-gmail/922493#922493

Comment: Thanks, suggested article is really good and helpful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native Gnome backup utility (you should have this already) can do the trick. Yes, duplicity can backup to Google Drive @Organic Marble. So it's an all in one solution and since it's a front-end to rsync, very powerful. I use it daily to back up to network storage, but I've noticed Google Drive as one of the options as are some other cloud solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There may be no one program to do this, but it's achievable using a mix of tools: `duplicity` or `deja-dup` to run the backup; `grive` or `insync` to synch with Google Drive. Scheduling can be done with internal tool options or `cron`.