# Crontab with external values

Tags: command-line, scripts, cron

i been trying to make a script,that generates a programmed backup using external   values to fill the crontab line.
so i been using :

```
read -p " text " var
for every variable for the crontab 
to get the values but i cant find a way to get does values in crontab.
```

can anyone help?

Comment: If your backup runs daily, create a normal script and place it in `/etc/cron.daily` and don't mess with `crontab` at all. Here is my daily backup: https://askubuntu.com/questions/917562/backup-linux-configuration-scripts-and-documents-to-gmail/922493#922493

Comment: it does't need to run daily, it runs only when the opcion is selected (using a menu), i solved the problem using: crontab * $var * * * command