# How to set up simple SMTP and POP services on one host to send/receive email on that host for app demo purposes

Tags: email

I have an application that can send and receive emails, however, I want to keep all communication within the one host as it is only for demonstrating the apps features. I guess I have to install SMTP and POP services but beyond that big picture I'm unsure how to proceed and how to do it so I don't have to become a email expert. I have done my googling but could not find anything appropriate. Any ideas or pointers would be appreciated - thank you.

Comment: POSTFIX is an option... [This thrad might help](https://askubuntu.com/q/1331555).

Comment: Apologies I should have mentioned that I am attempting to set this up on Ubuntu LTS 20.4 - is this not an appropriate forum?

Comment: Thanks @raffa - your suggestion is a good place to start. I was hoping for something not requiring so much investigation as my time is a bit constrained, however, I shall make a start. Thanks again.