# AbiWord File says Error and file cannot convert

Tags: files, libreoffice, helpfile, abiword, font-converter

I have been using AbiWord for the last few months working on a major project. I have gotten very far in my writing, but yesterday as soon as I pressed save my computer died. I did not think of it as a big deal until today I tried to open the file and it says "error unable to import [file name]". I downloaded a new software to open the file, and it opened, but the text is reading "##########". Is there anyway to open this file without losing all of the hard work I have spent months doing?

Comment: You haven't mentioned OS/release details (if nothing else, they tell us which software stack, or version of abiword you'll be using).  I just had a look at some .abw files, and the report as being XML (as I don't know your release, i looked at the first files I found).  I'd start by asking your system what type of file (`file`) it is, and view it (`view` or equiv.) to ensure the text is still there. I'd copy it, and try and restore the 'copy' so original is untouched.   Because *computer died* did you `fsck` before booting (I'd have done that before you touch the file first or log in)

Comment: @guiverc She has already opened the file. Nicole, assuming the corrupted file wasn't saved, try `cat ~/Documents/filename.abw` (replacing `Documents` with actual folder name and `filenname` with actual filename. It could be the bulk of information you want is still there and the text can be extracted (without formatting). That said you should backup your writings daily. I do this to my gmail account automatically with `cron`. To reply to someone here put `@` in front of their user name. eg @WinEunuuchs2Unix in your comment will let me know you replied.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I am not all too familiar with exactly what your suggesting, but it sounds as if it could atleast get me the text which is what I care about most! Could you walk me through the steps a little on how exactly to do this? Are you saying to do this [cat ~/Documents/filename.abw ] in a web browser? Also, I tried changing the file name to open it that way (a suggestion I seen online) which did not work. Will this affect the process of trying to restore?

Comment: No you need to open a terminal with `Alt`+`Ctrl`+`T` to enter commands and then type `exit` when done command entry to close the terminal. I'm at work on phone and am limited to assist for another 7.5 hours if you are around then.

Comment: @NicoleCheeks I'm at my computer now but not sure I understand where you are at. I can guarrantee you don't want to type `cat ~/Documents/filename.abw` because it's a made up name that doesn't exist. You need to replace `Documents` with the folder your file is in. You need to replace `filename` with the actual file. Leave `.abw` after the filename because that is the extension that AbiWord uses (on my system at least). If you don't know the filename you can change to the folder and use `ll` to list all the files in the folder. To change folder use `cd ~/foldername`, eg `cd ~/Documents`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I figured out how to open the terminal, but the codes on my computer are different than you explained. I don't know what command codes I am supposed to use. I tried dragging the file straight over to the terminal, but it did not open any of the document

Comment: I can help you in 3 hours but I'm at work now.  Basically you can just right click on file and select `open with gedit` then copy and paste good text into a new file.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using LibreOffice instead of AbiWord. I do use AbiWord at home only because it can print free barcodes I can use for work and LibreOffice cannot. Other than that AbiWord flickers inexplicably and lags every now and then. AbiWord doesn't even come close to the power of LibreOffice.

The issue of backups is important. As a minimum copying your documents folder to a USB flash drive after 10 or 20 hours of work is a good idea. The advantage is you can take your backup with you if your laptop burns down while you are away from home.

I have a more exotic automatic backup that copies all my writings for five years plus system configuration / settings I've made to tweak Ubuntu. Files are copied into a `.tar` archive which is compressed and emailed to my gmail account. The advantage of gmail is you can access your backups anywhere in the world and don't have to carry a USB thumb drive around in your pocket/purse. Gmail gives you 15 free GB of space which for me is a couple of years of daily backups before I have to start pruning (deleting) older backups. The setup is described here:

- [Backup Linux configuration, scripts and documents to Gmail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917562/backup-linux-configuration-scripts-and-documents-to-gmail/922493#922493)

I've answered other parts of your question in comments and after resolution the comments can be rolled up into this answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to open the file and it says "error unable to import [file name]".

When AbiWord begins loading the file and then exits with an error.  Validate the XML code contents of the file.  It is just a text file that you can open with Notepad++, Pluma, Vim, Nano, Emacs text editor.

https://jsonformatter.org/xml-validator  JSON  XML  Validator, was used to find a single error in XML code from AbiWord Editor  file Freds_document.abw   Use any XML Validator tool you find.  I ran the file Freds_document.abw through the JSON XML Validator to verify correct valid XML code.   Freds_document.abw.saved could also have been used by copying or moving to a different file name Like:  Fred_test1.abw

Abiword  had inserted an extra ' **props=""** '  in front of a  " **props="Courier xxxxx "**    Just delete the malformed string **props=""** from the text file.  ReValidate this XML file.   The JSON XML Validator showed me that it was in line 62 and character 331.  I Would not have found this
error that prevented me from loading file into AbiWord editor, with out an XML Validator tool.

Used a copy of the original file to validate and edit. Leave the original file untouched.  I Used filename Fred_Sample.abw  to edit and correct text problems.

[Abiword_recovery wordpress blog](https://stephenmw.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/abiword_recovery/)

[How to Open, Edit, Convert .ABW files May 2023](https://www.lifewire.com/abw-file-2619450)